# Find the average value, MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to find the average length of each Horror Series.

I have two collections Series and Books, books belongs to series and have field lenght, series got field "genre".

**Series**

```
{
  "_id": "61179c8d43400f31df195223",
  "name": "serie1",
   "book genre": Horror
},
{
  "_id": "61179c8d43400f31df195223",
  "name": "serie2",
   "book genre": Romance
},
{
  "_id": "61179c8d43400f31df195223",
  "name": "serie3",
   "book genre": Horror
},
{
  "_id": "61179c8d43400f31df195223",
  "name": "serie4",
   "book genre": Horror
},
```

**Books**

```
{
  "_id": "61179c8d43400f31df195223",
  "name": "book1",
   "lenght": 100,
   "serie": "serie1"
},
{
  "_id": "61179c8d43400f31df195223",
  "name": "book2",
   "lenght": 10,
   "serie": "serie3"
},
{
  "_id": "61179c8d43400f31df195223",
  "name": "book3",
   "lenght": 900,
   "serie": "serie3"
},
{
  "_id": "61179c8d43400f31df195223",
  "name": "book4",
   "lenght": 300,
   "serie": "serie1"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a pretty standard aggregation, here i'm using `$lookup`, `$avg` and `$map` to achieve the end results:

```
db.series.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "books",
      localField: "name",
      foreignField: "serie",
      as: "books"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      "book genre": 1,
      avg: {
        "$ifNull": [
          {
            $avg: {
              $map: {
                input: "$books",
                in: "$$this.lenght"
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ti1OJ5XYorT)

Comment: I need to find average lengh of all albums with genre="Horror"

Comment: So i have to add up all the lengths of horror albums and divide them by the number of them

Comment: we can sum up all the lengths of horror books and divided into the number of series with the horror genre

Comment: Yes, you could also just group and use the '$avg' operator, he does that for you

Answer (score 0):

Query

- finds the average per genre, for example average length of all horror movies
- group per genre
- lookup to get the lengths
- find the average

*Toms answer found average per series, if you don't want that maybe you want this? i am not sure. It would help if you sended us the expected output, i thought you wanted what Tom did also.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70380757-m)

```js
series.aggregate(
[{"$group":{"_id":"$book genre", "series":{"$push":"$name"}}},
 {"$lookup":
  {"from":"books",
   "localField":"series",
   "foreignField":"serie",
   "as":"series"}},
 {"$set": 
  {"book genre":"$_id",
   "_id":"$$REMOVE",
   "avgTime":{"$avg":"$series.lenght"}}}])
```